# Facebook Friends Data for comparison game

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have a small question, that doesn't let me sleep for days. 
You know applications, that compare your profile with your friends, e.g likes, movies, music, etc. How is it possible? I know that Facebook API provides access only for users who already used your application, for non-app users Facebook API provides the special method 'invitable_friends' to send invites, and that's all.

Are these fake applications?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Those apps will stop working after April 2015, when old v1.0 Apps will be upgraded to v2.0.

You can't get all friends with `/me/friends` anymore, only those who authorized your App. And friend permissions are gone, so even if you would be able to access all friends, you would not be able to compare data. The only way to implement this is by storing/caching data of authorized users and compare it with friends who authorized the App too.